# SML with lazy list function

Tags: sml, lazylist

I'm trying to make a function which can return the specific nth element of lazylist.

Here is what I made:

```
datatype 'a lazyList = nullList
                 | cons of 'a * (unit -> 'a lazyList)

fun Nth(lazyListVal, n) = (* lazyList * int -> 'a option *)
    let fun iterator (laztListVal, cur, target) =
        case lazyListVal of
             nullList => NONE
           | cons(value, tail) => if cur = target
                                  then SOME value
                                  else iterator (tail(), cur+1, target)
    in
        iterator(lazyListVal,1,n)
    end
```

I expected the result that as recusing proceeds, eventually the variable **`cur`** gets same as the variable **`target`**, and then the function iterator returns **`SOME value`** so it will return the final nth element.

But when I compile it and run, it only returns the very first element however I test with the lazylist objects.

Please figure what is the problem. I have no idea...

cf) I made another function which is relevant to this problem, the function that transforms lazylist into SML original list containing the first N values. Codes above:

```
fun firstN (lazyListVal, n) = (* lazyList * int -> 'a list *)
    let fun iterator (lazyListVal, cur, last) =
        case lazyListVal of
             nullList => []
           | cons(value, tail) => if cur = last
                                  then []
                                  else value::iterator(tail(),cur+1,last)
    in
        iterator(lazyListVal,0,n)
    end
```

The strange thing is the function firstN is properly working.

Comment: `firstN` works because it doesn't have the typo bug that `Nth` has. Its argument `lazyListVal` shadows its parent's argument of the same name, whereas `Nth` calls its own argument something different from its parent's and subsequently refers to its parent (the head of the list) rather than its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `iterator` function does `case lazyListVal of ...`, but the recursive tail is called **`laztListVal`**, so for every iteration, it keeps looking at the first list. Use better variable names to avoid this kind of "invisible" bug.

For a simpler definition of `nth`:

```
datatype 'a lazyList = NullList | Cons of 'a * (unit -> 'a lazyList)

fun nth (NullList, _) = NONE
  | nth (Cons (x, xs), 0) = SOME x
  | nth (Cons (_, xs), n) = nth (xs (), n-1)

val nats = let fun nat n = Cons (n, fn () => nat (n+1)) in nat 0 end

val ten = nth (nats, 10)
```

***Edit:*** While function pattern matching is ideal here, you could also have used a *case ... of ...* here. A helper function seems unnecessary, though, since you can simply use the input argument `n` as the iterator:

```
fun nth (L, n) =
    case (L, n) of
         (NullList, _) => NONE
       | (Cons (x, xs), 0) => SOME x
       | (Cons (_, xs), n) => nth (xs (), n-1)
```

You may however want to make the function more robust:

```
fun nth (L, n) =
    let fun nth' (NullList, _) = NONE
          | nth' (Cons (x, xs), 0) = SOME x
          | nth' (Cons (_, xs), n) = nth' (xs (), n-1)
    in if n < 0 then NONE else nth' (L, n) end
```

Here having a helper function ensures that `n < 0` is only checked once.

*(You could also `raise Domain`, since negative indices are not well-defined.)*

Comment: Then what is the reason for the function "firstN" not showing the same problem?

Comment: I tried to convert the `case...of` statement into **`function pattern matching`**, and surprisingly it works properly, as you suggested. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're welcome! But the problem is not related to function pattern matching vs. *case ... of*. You could make either work. I've provided an example of using *case ... of*.